# Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS dual boot with Windows 10, Windows 10 not showing in GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, windows-10

i am new to Ubuntu and hope someone is able to help, I'l give you as much information as possible:

I was running windows 10 on an ssd with a seperate 1 TB drive for data and wanted to try Ubuntu. Using windows disk manager I created a free partition on my ssd, I then tried to install Ubuntu (**14.04.3 LTS 64 bit**) onto the partition. However the installer did not recognize I had any operating system so gave me no "install alongside" option, thus i selected the "do something different" option. I selected my available partition and set it up as a primary partition with ext4 file system and proceeded to seemingly successfully install Ubuntu onto it. Upon restarting however my PC would boot up strait to windows without GRUB appearing at all.

After doing some research online I tried running the boot-repair wizard with Ubuntu live from a flash drive. I went through the recommended repair and eventual it told me everything should be OK and gave me this report:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/13219064

Now when i boot up GRUB appears but only gives me the options: Ubuntu, advanced options for Ubuntu & System setup. When running Ubuntu i can see my drive with all the windows files still inside it. Any suggestions on what I am missing to properly set up dual-boot?

Thankyou

Comment: Running `sudo update-grub` should add Windows to the list.

Comment: Should I add it as an answer?

Comment: Yea, it seems to have fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `sudo update-grub` will scan your drive for installed operating systems and will add ones it finds to the GRUB boot menu.